# Angular2 Default Route View

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I'm defining all my routes in `app.ts`

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/dashboard/...', component: Dashboard, name: 'Dashboard', useAsDefault: true }
)
```

On the dashboard, I have some nested routes relative to the dashbaord.
`dashboard.ts`

```
@Component({
    template: `<h1>this is dashboard default text</h1>
               <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
});
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/cmp1' , name: 'Cmp1' , component: cmp1}
    { path: '/cmp2' , name: 'Cmp2' , component: cmp2}
)
```

Now, If I go to the root url(i.e '/') it'll redirect me to `/dashboard` since it's the default one(but doesn't show cmp1/cmp2 yet, since I haven't click on the link on the dashboard yet).
But, if I try to visit `/dashboard` directly it shows a blank page.

I want the view of the dashboard to be shown when I access `/dashboard` directly(i.e from the browser address bar and without the child component views). It should behave as if I'm visiting root url `/`.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use your `now dashboard` as a parent for `actual default dashboard` as illustrated below *(almost similar to Günter's, and I also have mine like this)*

### `app.ts`

```ts
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/dashboard/...', component: Dashboard, name: 'Dashboard', useAsDefault: true }
)
```

---

### `dashboard.ts`

```ts
@Component({
    template: `<h1>this is dashboard text for all child routes
                    including default dashboard.
               </h1>
               <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
});
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/' , name: 'DashDefault' , component: DashDefaultCmp, useAsDefault: true},
    { path: '/cmp1' , name: 'Cmp1' , component: cmp1},
    { path: '/cmp2' , name: 'Cmp2' , component: cmp2}
)
```

---

### `dashDefaultCmp.ts`

***(keep it empty if you want)***

```ts
@Component({
        template: `<h1>this is your default dashboard.
                   </h1>`
    });
export class DashDefaultCmp{
}
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: hmm I thought of that, but creating another component just for that seemed a bit overkill. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set `useAsDefault` on one of your child routes as well, otherwise the router can't know what component to display if you just enter `/` or `/dashboard`

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/VCBWfA?p=preview)

**Update**

Use route to a child component that doesn't display anything.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'empty',
  template: ``
})
export class Empty {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'cmp1',
  template: `
  <h2>Cmp1</h2>
`
})
export class Cmp1 {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'cmp2',
  template: `
  <h2>Cmp2</h2>
`
})
export class Cmp2 {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
  <h2>Dashboard</h2>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/overview' , name: 'Overview' , component: Empty}
    { path: '/cmp1' , name: 'Cmp1' , component: Cmp1}
    { path: '/cmp2' , name: 'Cmp2' , component: Cmp2}
)
export class Dashboard {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
  <a href="#" [routerLink]="['Dashboard', 'Overview']">Dashboard</a>
  <a href="#" [routerLink]="['Dashboard', 'Cmp1']">Cmp1</a>
  <a href="#" [routerLink]="['Dashboard', 'Cmp2']">Cmp2</a>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/dashboard/...', component: Dashboard, name: 'Dashboard', useAsDefault: true },
])
export class App {
}
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GuTIKi?p=preview)

Comment: When I visit `/dashboard` it should show what ever there is on the dashboard template(without the child components).  
If I set a child component as default, then it will redirect me to that route automatically when I visit `/dashboard`

Comment: So when you enter `/dashboard` you don't want to show any `CmpX`? Then you need a `/dashboard` route (without `/...`).

Comment: `/dashboard` where? on `app.ts`?  
I can't create two routes with the same component, can I?  

It shows me this error->  
`Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterOutlet -> Router).`    
`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Child routes are not allowed for "/dashboard". Use "..." on the parent's route path.`

Comment: I updated my answer. There might be better solutions though. I don't have too much experience with the router myself yet.